# Where is Degree-Diameter Problem table?

Tags: graph-theory

Degree-Diameter Problem is a well known problem in graph theory.
http://combinatoricswiki.org/wiki/The_Degree/Diameter_Problem

I found the table for small diameter and small degree.
http://combinatoricswiki.org/wiki/The_Degree_Diameter_Problem_for_General_Graphs

I'd like to find a table for diameter 2 and large degree.

Comment: Are you sure they are known (for small diameter, $2$, and large degree)?

Comment: I don't know it.

Comment: From looking at the table, it appear that for diameter 2 the answer is unknown for large degree (it appears to only have bounds for most degrees... and certainly not known for degrees above 20).

Comment: Using my laptop, I compute the graph with diameter 2 and maximum degree 36 ( minimum degree 35 ) and 1053 vertices ( 81% of Moore bound ) ...

Comment: How do you know that is the best possible?

Comment: sorry...the general construction that is known has larger vertices than my graph. Using finite projective plane, the graph with diameter 2 and maximum degree 33 and 1057 vertices still exists. Thank you Travis!

Comment: I found the graph with degree 306 and diameter 2 and 88723 vertices. Is it a new result?